# Scroll view onendreached not working in react native

Tags: react-native, horizontalscrollview, react-native-scrollview

I am using scrollview in react native but it's onendreached not working how can i use onendreached in  horizontal scroll view

```
<Animated.ScrollView
        horizontal
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH}></Animated.ScrollView>
```

I need horizontal flatlist in this if i use horizontal in the scroll view. then flatlist onendreached not working. If i remove horizotal from scroll view then onscroll not working in the scrollview.
So  i am looking for a function that will load more data as it will reach on the end of scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

U can use map function inside the scroll view to render your items. Then u can use this method inside a ScrollView

```
onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
  if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
      ///// your code goes here
  }
}}
```

where isCloseToBottom functions is as follows

```
    isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
        const paddingToright = 20;
        return layoutMeasurement.width + contentOffset.x >= contentSize.width - paddingToright;
    };
```

Comment: Hello @SardarUsama. i tried to use this. but it is not working. i am using horizontal scrolling